# Force icon to stay outside notification tray

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-registry, icons, notification-area

Using the mouse, I can drag an icon placed in the notification tray and move it outside.

[image]
[image]

Can I do that but from an automated script (so maybe using the Windows Registry), for an arbitrary program icon?

Comment: In short, Microsoft specifically designed this setting to not be changeable programmatically to avoid abuse by software vendors.

Comment: @Worthwelle if you can link a MS document that states this, you can write it as an answer

Comment: This is explained in the answer to the question that this is a duplicate of. Since your question was closed as a duplicate, I can't add an answer. See the link at the top of your question under *This question already has answers here: *